# DynamoDB Shedlock Implementation

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, scheduler, shedlock

I am trying to solve the issue of Cron job running on different instances. I understand that we need to create a shedlock table, but I am unclear about the columns and table name to be used.

I have read shedlock documentation and it says :

Please note that the lock table must be created externally with _id as a partition key. DynamoDBUtils#createLockTable may be used for creating it programmatically. A table definition is available from DynamoDBLockProvider's Javadoc.

I could not find DynamoDBLockProvider's Javadoc anywhere.

Also can we have the shedlock in another Database. I mean if our Database is in say Oracle database , can we put the shedlock in DynamoDB?

Comment: Find DynamoDBLockProvider's Javadoc in the [DynamoDBLockProvider source code](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock/blob/master/providers/dynamodb/shedlock-provider-dynamodb2/src/main/java/net/javacrumbs/shedlock/provider/dynamodb2/DynamoDBLockProvider.java).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.